# When I read from a file, The last letter is printed twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an encrypted message in storage.txt I read this message from a text file along with the offset, decrypt it with the offset and print the decrypted message. The problem I have is that when I print the decrypted message the last letter is printed twice. For example if the decrypted message is 'dog' it will print 'dogg'

```
file=open('storage.txt','r')
encoded=file.readline()
offset2=file.readline()
file.close()
for letters in encoded:

    if letters==" ":
        num=32

    elif letters.isalpha():
        num=ord(letters)
        num-=int(offset2)

        if letters.islower():
           if num>ord('z'):
              num-=26
           elif num<ord('a'):
              num+=26

        elif letters.isupper():
           if num>ord('Z'):
              num-=26
           elif num<ord('A'):
              num+=26

ans=chr(num)
print(ans, end='')
```

storage.txt would look like this: (the message translates to dog when decrypted with offset of 1)

eph
1

Thanks a bunch if you can help.

Comment: You should edit-in an example `storage.txt`.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but I have some naming advice. `letter` would make more sense than `letters`, because the variable only ever contains a single character at any point in time. `letters` implies that it's a sequence of multiple characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
encoded=file.readline()
```

When `readline` reads a line, it includes the newline character at the end of the line. So even though "eph" looks like it's three characters long in the text file, `encoded` will actually be `"eph\n"`. Try stripping the input of whitespace before doing anything with it.

```
encoded=file.readline().strip()
```

Without the `strip`, your loop will iterate four times, with `letters` being "\n" on the final loop. Neither `letters==" "` nor `letters.isalpha()` will be true, so `num` will retain the value that it had in the previous iteration, and the character will be printed again.